# Using mscoree.tlb inside a unity script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I wish to make use of mscoree.tlb inside my unity project, but it fails to build. Inside my visual studio it is compiles just fine. Any way around this?

Here is the code that makes use of mscoree

```
        private static IList<AppDomain> GetAppDomains()
        {
            IList<AppDomain> iList = new List<AppDomain>();
            IntPtr enumHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
            mscoree.ICorRuntimeHost host = new mscoree.CorRuntimeHostClass();
            try
            {
                host.EnumDomains(out enumHandle);
                while (true)
                {
                    object domain;
                    host.NextDomain(enumHandle, out domain);

                    if (domain == null)
                    {
                        break;
                    }

                    AppDomain appDomain = (AppDomain) domain;
                    iList.Add(appDomain);
                }
                return iList;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return null;
            }
            finally
            {
                host.CloseEnum(enumHandle);
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(host);
            }
        }
```

Apart from above code I am just displaying the appdomain names to a Canvas>Text element.

Here is the specific error unity gives me

```
Assets/Appdomains.cs(38,13): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `mscoree' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?
```

Comment: Pretty sure Unity uses Mono when it runs, it may compile in Visual Studio, but I doubt its loaded into the MS .NET runtime.

Comment: what are you trying to do? Why host the CLR inside the CLR?

Comment: @pm100 I wish to view all the appdomains in the current process(the friendlyName property is what I want from them actually)